# SQL Conditional Column Existence

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, exists

Can I somehow select a column if exists in a view, but ignore the column if it does not exist?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyView' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumn')
            THEN MyView.MyColumn
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [Sometimes]
FROM
    MyView
```

Right now, that returns a "Msg 207 Invalid column name" error.

Perhaps some option to ignore that error is possible?

Comment: The necessity raises bigger questions about your data model.

Comment: I agree.  If only it was "my" data model... then I'd change it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using **dynamic SQL**:

```
declare @sql varchar(200)   
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyView' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumn') 
BEGIN
    select  @sql = "SELECT Column1 AS TheColumn1, MyColumn from MyView"
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select  @sql = "SELECT Column1 AS TheColumn1, null AS MyColumn from MyView"
END 

-- executes dynamic sql
EXEC @sql
```

Comment: There is no requirement for dynamic SQL in your example! The `if`/`else` is sufficient.

Comment: This worked.  I hate having to resort to dynamic SQL.  It always feels like "cheating" to me.  I might as well script some logic in some other language, heh.  But it works!  And probably as good as I'm going to get today.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Almost worked for me... in SQL Server 2016, I had to set `varchar(200)` to `nvarchar(max)` and run `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` instead of `EXEC @sql`. `EXEC (@sql)` may also work: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost757517.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. The column-access has to be compiled, if nothing else, and this happens before the expression that suppresses it is evaluated. You need to generate SQL on-the-fly for this.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is

```
if EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyView' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumn')
Select MyView.MyColumn from MyView
else
Select NULL MyColumn
```

Comment: For SQL 2008 R2 this still gave me Msg 207 Invalid column name.

Comment: @EdGruberman you are right, i had to remove the from MyView in the else part

Comment: Your tenacity is appreciated bernd_k.  However, this edit still returned the Msg 207 error for me on Line 2.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (Intel X86) 
 Sep 16 2010 20:09:22 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: ) -- MyView does not exist in my database and I get the following result :MyColumn
-----------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
Perhaps it depends on some setting?

Comment: I tried it against SQL-Server 2000 an SQL-Server 2005 too and got the same result. Even Query Analyzer (sql 2000) against SQL-server 2008 showed no error msg.

Comment: Ah, it's because MyView does not exist in your test. I get the same results as you if MyView does not exist. But my question is about adjusting the output based upon the existence of a column in an existing view.

Comment: Yes that's true. In this case you need dynamic SQL.